# is it ok for Keras not to load much CPU & GPU?

Tags: python-3.x, keras

My PC is not so great: i7-2600 & GeForce GTX 970.
But when I start the script which classifies photos with CNN my system is not loaded much: CPU for 20%, GPU for 5%.

It looks like GPU is available:

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
[name: "/device:CPU:0"
device_type: "CPU"
memory_limit: 268435456
locality {
}
incarnation: 4011293230370962537
, name: "/device:GPU:0"
device_type: "GPU"
memory_limit: 3110401638
locality {
  bus_id: 1
  links {
  }
}
incarnation: 3815751383857027347
physical_device_desc: "device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 970, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 5.2"
]
```

My Keras version is

```
print(keras.__version__)
2.3.1
```

My Tensorflow version is

```
print(tensorflow.__version__)
1.14.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the GPU fraction you want to use by running this snippet:

```
gpu_options = tf.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=1) #number between 0 and 1
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=gpu_options))
```

From experience, you have to run it right after doing `import tensorflow`. Restart the kernel if you need to.

Comment: Done, but nothing changed after I had restarted the kernel and the script. CPU is still at 20%, core at 5% By the way dedicated GPU memory is used the same as before at 3.4 of 4 GB. Do you think this is my system bottleneck?